# 3rd Party Encryption Managed Assembly won’t load in Windows 7 Pro x64

Tags: c#, dll

I’m a C# newbie who wrote a program in VS 2010 C# in 2010 to encrypt/decrypt data using a 3rd party managed assembly (EncryptionManager.DLL).
Program runs fine in XP Pro SP3 with .Net 3.5 SP1 installed.
On Windows 7 Pro x64 with .NET 3.5 enabled, program fails with the following error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'EncryptionManager, Version=1.0.2978.16361, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=53b6ffdb4dc98f0f' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   File name: 'EncryptionManager, Version=1.0.2978.16361, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=53b6ffdb4dc98f0f'

DLL is installed in the GAC and is in the program search path.
DLL is loaded implicitly (reference compiled).
Manifest and DLL system versions match:

```
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="EncryptionManager.dll" size="25896">
    <assemblyIdentity name="EncryptionManager" version="1.0.2978.16361" publicKeyToken="53B6FFDB4DC98F0F" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" />
    <hash>
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>qAxbPPkBK+n8/jtJ8pnjvJg/E2A=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

What do I need to do to make this run on Windows 7?

Comment: [A DLL or executable is loaded as a 64-bit assembly, but it contains 32-bit features or resources. For example, it relies on COM interop or calls methods in a 32-bit dynamic link library.

To address this exception, set the project's Platform target property to x86 (instead of x64 or AnyCPU) and recompile.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx)  Or one of the other suggestions listed on that page.

Comment: That was it! Many thanks. Compiling as x86 resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Set your project to use x86 instead of Any CPU as a target.

Comment: To add to this, if you have your project set to Any CPU, then .Net will compile the byte code to x64 on a 64bit machine. 64bit executables can't reference 32bit DLLs since the references/pointers are a different size, among other things.

Comment: That was it!   Many thanks.  Compiling as x86 resolved the issue.